# Function of a class returning an array that is declared after the class

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-7

I somehow haven't dealt with this problem before. I have a class

```
  TRoom = class
   private
     width, length, X1,X2,Y1,Y2, index: integer;
   public
     function draw: RoomArr;      
     procedure setparam;
     function getparam: integer;
  end;
```

Now, below that, because Delphi 7 can't return Arrays of TClass, I have declared this:

```
RoomArr = Array of TRoom;
```

This somehow fixes the problem. No idea why, I just found this solution on the internet

I am using the "RoomArr" in other functions and it works fine, as expected. 
But as the array is declared after the class (otherwise it would not know the class TRoom), TRoom itself (more precisely the function "draw") cannot use it.

Is there any way to bypass this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error in title: *function

Comment: I don't make much sense of this, but *otherwise it would not know the class TRoom* sounds like you are looking for so called forward declaration.

Comment: You really need to  be careful about returning an Array of Objects(TRoom)...who created the objects...and who is responsible for releasing said objects...

Comment: Why do you think Delphi 7 can't return an array of TClass? (That's not what you'd want to do in this case anyway, but I don't know why you think it isn't possible.)

Answer (score 5):

You need a [forward declaration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes):

```
type
  TRoom = class; // forward declaration

  TRoomArr = array of TRoom; // so that array type can be declared before class

  TRoom = class
    function Draw: TRoomArr; // and used by class
  end;
```

Comment: Good. You should pick one of the answers and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A forward declaration of `TRoom`:

```
Type
  TRoom = class; // forward declaration

  RoomArr = Array of TRoom;

  TRoom = class
    ...
    function draw: RoomArr;
  end;
```

The [forward declaration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes) must be completed in the same type section.

Comment: thanks! will keep it in mind if something similar happens again